# Angularjs to display 2 arrays from a json object in two different tabledata of a tablerow

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object containing two array objects. The object is store in ***$scope.person***. Now i want to display the Likes array in first column and Dislikes array in the second column of the table. Assume that the length of both arrays are similar so no. of rows will be similar as well. What could be the best way to do it? 
Check the JSON object below.

```
{
  "name": "Justin Clark",
  "rating": 3,
  "img": "http://www.fillmy.com/200/200",
  "Description": "Gluten­free cray cardigan vegan. Lumbersexual pork belly blog, fanny pack put a bird on it selvage",
  "Likes": [
    "Dogs",
    "Long walks on the beach",
    "Chopin",
    "Tacos"
  ],
  "Dislikes": [
    "Birds",
    "Red things",
    "Danish food",
    "Dead Batteries"
  ]
}
```

The table structure looks like this.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead> 
    <tr> <th>Likes</th> <th>Dislikes</th></tr> 
  </thead>   
  <tbody> 
    <tr ng-repeat="pl in person"> 
      <td>{{pl.Likes}}</td> <td>{{pl.Dislikes}}</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you need two seperate `ng-repeat` for both of them

Comment: i tried doing that, but im not sure how to do it. how can we have two ng-repeat in one **tr** ?

Comment: added a simpler way to do this as an answer. Check below.

Comment: What has number of rows got to do with number of columns? Number of rows will correspond to the number of person objects. Whilst the number of columns will depend upon the number of attributes in each person object, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the `ng-repeat` on one of the arrays (take `Likes`) and using the `$index` of `ng-repeat` you can have the `Dislikes` array mapped as well.

Something like this..

```
<tr ng-repeat="like in data.Likes">
  <td>{{like}}</td> 
  <td>{{data.Dislikes[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O3tufsArA5n1iWmOduQP?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you tanmay. That works. Can we do like: setting the ng-repeat="like in data" and have the td saying {{data.Likes[$index]}} for Likes and {{data.Dislikes[$index]}} for Dislikes?

Comment: @SarmadAsif absolutely

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div class="media-list" ng-controller="dishDetailController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="customer in data">
        {{customer}}
        <td>{{customer.Likes}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.Dislikes}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/kDJe6wQ0WJnFvQ7B03Oz?p=preview)**

**EDIT:**

Based on assumption your data is not an array,

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/EjyxfNtiY9Vg5H8oViXE?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for solution but in the demo, it doesnt display in separate rows.

Comment: you need to display the child array as rows?

Comment: I want to show Likes array in first column as different rows and Dislike array in the second column as different rows. Since the length of both arrays are similar, which is 4. So there would be 4 rows in total.

Comment: @SarmadAsif I thought your data is an array, check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/kDJe6wQ0WJnFvQ7B03Oz?p=preview

Comment: @tanmay No i dint copy, its a simple thing bro. i mentioned the reason why it dint work, i was under the impression its a json array. If you want i can delete my answer.

Comment: @Sajeetharan how could you exactly give `width="200px"` and exact indent if you didn't copy.

Comment: i actually saw your answer and realised it as an object and i upvoted yours

Comment: @tanmay do you want to delete this answer? you could understand from the comments